# ubuntu 14.04 overheating hp g6 1301ax

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, overheating

I'm new to linux so bear with my naivety. I was running ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and had installed tlp and switched off discrete graphics and everything was fine except for the screen would not turn on after suspension. To correct this I installed the proprietory amd drivers ( flgrx-updates) and since then my laptop has started overheating. I reversed the drives to the open soirce pre installed drivers via the software center but nothing changed. I cannot change display brightness either. Also the output of sensors command is displaying only 2 temps instead of four which it displayed earlier.